# How to implement Login functionality using ASP.NET WebForms and existing SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a SQL Server database that I made using Visual Studio's LocalDB.
It has 5 tables, one for the Employee information and credentials, one for the location codes of the offices of the company and others for the meetings he attended and the tasks assigned to him.

I am mainly looking to implement Login functionality on my WebApp. How do I access the SQL database and implement Login?
I have currently connected the database and used ADO.NET Entity Model to access the database. I am looking to avoid stored procedures. It would be best if the someone explained how to do this with ADO.NET Entity Model and the Login control.

Comment: it seems you are looking for database connection string? is it true?

Comment: @AliAdl That's just one part of it. I managed to get the connection string once I used the ADO.NET Entity Data Model to import my database into the application.
I'm looking for a way to use the Login control so that upon 'submit' the supplied credentials are matched with the entries in my database and a session (by way of a cookie or anything else) is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own table with login credential{like username, password,role(if you want to set)}, then after just connect your table with the login template to check the credential.

These links will help you out:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/login-control-in-Asp-Net-3-5/
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Login-Form-example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the resources. They are almost exactly what I was looking for. The only problem is that I was hoping there would be away to skip the stored procedures and implement it as a server side script (in the aspsnippets article).
Also, is it ADO.NET in the c-sharpcorner article?

Comment: You welcome. Yes you can skip stored procedures and implement your select query with sql datareader or sql dataadapter what ever you want like mention in c-Sharpcorner article. and yes the c-sharpcorner article is ADO.NET part.

Comment: Can I issue SQL queries using the Entity model?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use Membership class, install the required db objects via aspnet_regsql or automatically created if it does not exist by the framework. the Login control for example uses it internally by calling Membership.Validate(username, password) for example.

Otherwise, if you insist to use another data framework such as entity model then you may create your own table for storing users, roles etc. there should be plenty examples of this. You still can use the Login control and handle the event such as LoggingIn, LoggedIn to plug in your own codes.

Comment: I want to avoid using the Membership database because I already have a database to manage the users. I just want to know how to interface with the database from my application. I know there are Stored Procedures, issuing SQL queries using datareader/adapter (ADO.NET) and Entity model.
I currently want to use my own Membership class so I am writing a custom Membership class.

Comment: In such cases, if you still want to use Membership API, then you just need to extend MembershipProvider and overrides all the required methods you may map your User model to MembershipUser. Otherwise, create your own and just plug-in your codes to built-in security controls through some events.

Comment: Thanks. I will do just that.